# packet received from a different subnet

Tags: linux, sockets, networking, tcp

I have a server on pc with address 192.168.1.3, and a client socket bound with address in different subnet 92.1.1.1. client and server are connected via a switch.

from wireshark, I could see the interface 192.168.1.3 receives the packets from 92.1.1.1, but at udp server level, there are no packets received. 
Are the packets get dropped because they are from different subnet? But at which layer are they dropped? How do I check what happened?

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Comment: Kernel might drop the packets. Try `netstat -s` to debug the reason...